# How can I set min-height in Tailwind?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I've got an inline-block that should be at least 1 rem high but will expand if the content doesn't fit. Without Tailwind, I'd solve it the following way.

```
<div style="display:inline-block; min-height:1rem;">
    content...
</div>
```

However, the only min-h classes supplied by Tailwind are `min-h-0`, `min-h-full`, and `min-h-screen`. So which class should I add here to write it the "Tailwind way"?

```
<div class="inline-block ???">
    content...
</div>
```

Comment: Checkout tailwind "JIT (just-in-time)" feature. You can do crazy things like class="h-[1rem]"

Comment: Thanks @MinSomai I'll check it out! I figured this would be such a common use-case that I'm missing something. This is my first "real" project with Tailwind.

Comment: We used to code custom css for things which are of arbitrary values. Anyway, this new tailwind feature solves most of these cases.

Comment: @MinSomai Just checked it out, I see that JIT was introduced in Tailwind 2.1. Unfortunately this project is using 2.0 at the moment and it's not in my power to bump that!

Comment: you have two options AFAIK: define your own min-h-1rem or something in tailwind.config.js or write a new class.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are two ways to do this: with the new just-in-time mode or by extending the config.

## Using JIT

The JIT (just in time) mode generates the CSS as you need it. So instead of generating all the classes then purging unused ones, it only generates utilities as you use them. This means it's both stupidly fast and can be used to create arbitrary classes on the fly.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#enabling-jit-mode

Starting with v3 of TailwindCSS, the just-in-time mode will be turned on by default.

If you enable JIT, you can use these classes:

```
<div class="inline-block min-h-[1rem]">
    content...
</div>
```

The brackets denotes that this is an arbitrary value not in the config.

## Extending the config

You can also add all spacing values to the min-height utilities by extending your config. Note that by extending the theme, we are not overriding any of the previous values for `min-height`. We're just adding new utilities.

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      minHeight: (theme) => ({
        ...theme('spacing'),
      }),
    }
  },
}
```

This means you can use `min-h-4` just like normal height utilities.

```
<div class="inline-block min-h-4">
    content...
</div>
```

---

Personally, I actually use both JIT and the config extension. This means I can use arbitrary values if I want, but I also can use the normal CSS spacing values for things like `min-height`.

Comment: Thanks you! I ended up extending the config. Thanks a lot for your example code!

Comment: This is great. Would love see the `Extending the config` solution become default!

Comment: why though isn't setting an integer value for `min-h-` the default behavior like it is with `height` and `width`? Is it not very common or perhaps discouraged?